# How to patch globally in pytest?

Tags: python, tdd, pytest, python-mock

I use pytest quite a bit for my code. Sample code structure looks like this. The entire codebase is `python-2.7`

```
core/__init__.py
core/utils.py

#feature

core/feature/__init__.py
core/feature/service.py

#tests
core/feature/tests/__init__.py
core/feature/tests/test1.py
core/feature/tests/test2.py
core/feature/tests/test3.py
core/feature/tests/test4.py
core/feature/tests/test10.py
```

The `service.py` looks something like this:

```
from modules import stuff
from core.utils import Utility


class FeatureManager:
    # lots of other methods
    def execute(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._execute_step1(*args, **kwargs)
        # some more code
        self._execute_step2(*args, **kwargs)
        utility = Utility()
        utility.doThings(args[0], kwargs['variable'])
```

All the tests in `feature/tests/*` end up using `core.feature.service.FeatureManager.execute` function. However `utility.doThings()` is not necessary for me to be run while I am running tests. I need it to happen while the production application runs but I do not want it to happen while the tests are being run.

I can do something like this in my `core/feature/tests/test1.py`

```
from mock import patch

class Test1:
   def test_1():
       with patch('core.feature.service.Utility') as MockedUtils:
           exectute_test_case_1()
```

This would work. However I added `Utility` just now to the code base and I have more than 300 test cases. I would not want to go into each test case and write this `with` statement.

I could write a `conftest.py` which sets a os level environment variable based on which the `core.feature.service.FeatureManager.execute` could decide to not execute the `utility.doThings` but I do not know if that is a clean solution to this issue.

I would appreciate if someone could help me with global patches to the entire session. I would like to do what I did with the `with` block above globally for the entire session. Any articles in this matter would be great too.

TLDR: How do I create session wide patches while running pytests?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I added a file called `core/feature/conftest.py` that looks like this

```
import logging
import pytest
from unittest import mock


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def default_session_fixture(request):
    """
    :type request: _pytest.python.SubRequest
    :return:
    """
    log.info("Patching core.feature.service")
    patched = mock.patch('core.feature.service.Utility')
    patched.__enter__()

    def unpatch():
        patched.__exit__()
        log.info("Patching complete. Unpatching")

    request.addfinalizer(unpatch)
```

This is nothing complicated. It is like doing

```
with mock.patch('core.feature.service.Utility') as patched:
    do_things()
```

but only in a session-wide manner.

Comment: How can we get call_count here? This is the solution I am after but need to assert it gets called x times

Comment: Solved it, keep the value of __enter__()

Comment: If you add the fixture as an arg on the applied test, it can access it just like using @mock.patch or with mock.patch. => return patched.__enter__()

Comment: good to see you have figured it out. Did not see it in time to respond

Comment: where is your "mock" defined or imported? ```= mock.patch...```

Comment: You should use the start and stop methods and not enter/exit: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-methods-start-and-stop

Answer (score 19):

Building on the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38782306/11163122) for a similar use case (4.5 years later), using unittest.mock's [`patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) with a `yield` also worked:

```py
from typing import Iterator
from unittest.mock import patch

import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def default_session_fixture() -> Iterator[None]:
    log.info("Patching core.feature.service")
    with patch("core.feature.service.Utility"):
        yield
    log.info("Patching complete. Unpatching")
```

---

**Aside**

For this answer I utilized `autouse=True`.  In my actual use case, to integrate into my unit tests on a test-by-test basis, I utilized `@pytest.mark.usefixtures("default_session_fixture")`.

---

**Versions**

```
Python==3.8.6
pytest==6.2.2
```

Comment: @ThunderPhoenix multiple ways.  To name a few, you could use `patch.multiple` (if patching multiple places in same object) or multiple `patch`es in the `with` statement (if patching several disjoint objects)

Comment: Could you update your answer and show how it can be done in both cases?

Comment: "I didn't use autouse=True" - you did?

Comment: Good point @kev sorry that was confusing.  I cleaned up the Aside to make what I meant more clear

Comment: This falls apart if the global-used reference is imported like `from mod import MyClass`. The path you need to pass to patch will differ because it needs to be prefixed by the _importing_ class. `https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch`