# Better way to mock test class methods

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I have a class which uses some http and elastic in init, I would like to find a better way to run mock tests without patch every single test cases.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init(self):
        self.es=ElasticSearch()
        self.http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    
    def method_1():
        xxxxx


    def method_2():
        xxxx

    def method_100():
        xxxx
```

Test cases

```
@mock.patch(ElasticSearch)
@mock.patch(PoolManager)
test_method_1():
    class_instance = MyClass()
    class_instance.method_1()
    assert xxxxx

@mock.patch(ElasticSearch)
@mock.patch(PoolManager)
test_method_2():
    class_instance = MyClass()
    class_instance.method_2()
    assert xxx
```

Is there an easy way without specifying mock.patch repeatedly for each test?

Comment: Put the patching into a fixture with `autouse=True`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to patch globally in pytest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38765917/how-to-patch-globally-in-pytest)

Comment: You have a typo in `__init__`.