# override SQlAlchemy context manager for all tests

Tags: sqlalchemy, pytest

I use FastApi with SqlAlchemy  as `context manager`

```
@contextmanager
def get_session(): # need to patch all over tests files
    session_ = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield session_
    except Exception as e:
        session_.rollback()
```

```
router.py

@router.get('/get_users'): 
def get_users(): # No dependencies
    with get_session() as session: 
        users = session.query(Users).all()
    return users
```

I need to override `get_session`  during all my tests (I use pytest)

I could do it with `@patch` and patch all test. But it's not  most effective  way because i need to use decorator to patch in each test file, correct specify full path.

I wonder is there quick way to do it in one place or maybe use fixture?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the approach in [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928873/11612918): define a pytest fixture with arguments `scope="session", autouse=True`, patching the context manager. If you need, you can also provide a new callable:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from unittest.mock import patch

import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True, new_callable=fake_session)
def default_session_fixture():
    with patch("your_filename.get_session"):
        yield

@contextmanager
def fake_session():
    yield ... # place your replacement session here
```

As a side note, I would highly recommend using [FastAPI's dependency injection](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/) for handling your SQLAlchemy session, especially since it has [built in support for exactly this kind of patching](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-dependencies/).

Comment: It doesn't work, new_callable argument is not accepted argument in fixture. It must be in patch. But nevertheless it has no effect